# how to send through onclick="function(this)"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, so I have got two problems here. First I will show you the html.

```
<div id="servicesAvailable">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="servicesAvailable[]">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>     
        <span>Add another service</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Okay so i want the user to be able to click the '.fa-plus-circle' class to add another div inside #servicesAvailable.

So i did this:(i know that people will say why dont you write $() instead of jQuery(), but its fine like this).

```
jQuery('fa-plus-circle').click(function(){
    jQuery('#servicesAvailable').append(
        '<div>
             <input type="text" name="servicesAvailable[]" onclick="addServices(this)">
             <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
             <span> Add another service</span>
        </div>'
    );
    jQuery(this).next().hide();
    jQuery(this).hide();

});
```

Ok so with this it should work fine. It actually works the first time i click the class. Then when i click on the fa-plus-circle class on the new appended section it just doesn't do anything. Even if i put console.log('here'); inside the jQuery click function it doesn't log.

So to start of if anyone can point out something i did wrong there then great!.

However i have tried now to change the way i do this to get it to work which leads the the title question 'how to send through onclick="function(this)"'

```
<div id="servicesAvailable">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="servicesAvailable[]">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" onclick="addServices(this)"></i>     
        <span>Add another service</span>
    </div>
</div>

        function addServices(this)
        {
            jQuery('#servicesAvailable').append(
                '<div>
                     <input type="text" name="servicesAvailable[]" onclick="addServices(this)">
                     <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                     <span> Add another service</span>
                 </div>'
            );
            this.next().hide();
            this.hide();
        }
```

now straight away in the console before i do any thing is has

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this
function addServices(this)
```

Can anyone advise what i am doing wrong in either cases to get this to work please?

Ill admit i'm not 100% which the second way but i'm pretty sure the first attempt should work.

Comment: 'this' parameter name can make a conflict here, try to use it addServices(ground) like that

Comment: you need to add teh click event to the newly created <i>

Comment: @ArunPJohny The problem here is not the context `this`. If that would be the case the error would be something else. Not *Syntax Error* `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this`

Comment: do you really need `this` here? I don't think so. you would use `this` if you have to pass an attribute like `this.attributeName` where `attributeName` is the name of the attribute or if you need some extra reference. This should work without `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error is **Syntax Error** `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this`.

Your string is not completed on the same line. For multiline strings use `\` at the end of line

```
function addServices(el) {
    jQuery('#servicesAvailable').append(
        '<div>\
            <input type="text" name="servicesAvailable[]" onclick="addServices(this)">\
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>\
            <span> Add another service</span>\
        </div>'
    );
    jQuery(el).hide().next().hide();
}
```

Comment: I agree. It's a syntax error. And one thing Tushar, I think passing `this` in `addServices()` is not needed either I feel.

Answer (score 2):

This is your working code:

```
$('#servicesAvailable').on("click", ".fa-plus-circle",function () {
    $('#servicesAvailable').append('<div>\
     <input type="text" name="servicesAvailable[]" onclick="addServices(this)">\
     <i class="fa fa-plus-circle">click to add</i>\
     <span> Add another service</span>\
</div>');
    jQuery(this).next().hide();
    jQuery(this).hide();

});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sp3qds56/)

Answer (score 0):

The event was binded only to the existing element, and not with the dynamically added elements. To bind events with dynamically added elements you need to update

```
jQuery('fa-plus-circle').click(function(){
```

to

```
jQuery("#servicesAvailable").on("click", "fa-plus-circle", function(){
```

For reference - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: this just made it unresponsive, so when i now click on the fa class it doesnt do anything

Comment: Then there must be some other issue with your code. The solution to problem of event binding is as stated above.